# RDF - Right Strategy for defining new namespaces

Tags: namespaces, rdf

I am struggling to find the right strategy for defining new namespaces.

## Strategy 1:

Use standard namespaces whenever possible - understood

## Strategy 2:

Create own namespace to basically increase readability and maintainability, e.g.

```
@prefix dimd: <https://www.company.com/products/di#> .

dimd:Table a rdfs:Resource ;
    rdfs:subClassOf dimd:Dataset .

dimd:column rdfs:range dimd:Column ;
    rdfs:domain dimd:Dataset .
```

## Strategy for long URIs?

But how do I deal with the long URIs e.g. datasets with columns

```
<https://mycompany.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv> a dimd:Dataset ;
dimd:column <https://mycompany.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv/SINGLE> .

<https://mycompany.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv/SINGLE> dimd:Column ;
xsd:boolean .
```

Is there a notation to replace "https://mycompany.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog" with e.g. "instance"?

```
instance:/catalog/EU/Population.csv a dimd:Dataset ;
dimd:column instance:/catalog/EU/Population.csv/SINGLE> .

instance/catalog/EU/Population.csv/SINGLE> dimd:Column ;
xsd:boolean .
```

In this case the concept of namespace/prefix is not working due to the slashes, is it?

Comment: Is `@base` okay to use?

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in the local part of your prefixed names [need to be](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#reserved) escaped with a backslash:

```
instance:\/catalog\/EU\/Population.csv
instance:\/catalog\/EU\/Population.csv\/SINGLE
```

To make these names more friendly and shorter, you could create a prefix for each catalog (with a trailing slash):

```
@prefix eu-population: <https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv/> .
@prefix us-population: <https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/US/Population.csv/> .

<https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv> a dimd:Dataset ;
                                                                              dimd:column eu-population:SINGLE .
```

#### File vs. Dataset

You might want to differentiate between the catalog file and the dataset this file contains. This would not only allow you to make different statements about each entity (creation/update date, author etc.), but you could also use the shorter prefix to refer to the dataset:

```
eu-population: a dimd:Dataset ;
               ex:file <https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv> ;
               dimd:column eu-population:SINGLE .
```

So `https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv` would be the URI for the file, and `https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/shared/catalog/EU/Population.csv/` would be the URI for the dataset. (You could also consider omitting the `.csv` from the dataset URI, so that you don’t refer to a file type in case it changes in the future.)

However, if these URIs aren’t under your control, you should follow the definitions of the publisher.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I need to append a folder structure to a namespace, e.g. 

@prefix eu-population: <https://example.com/sub/dataset/connection/> and the item needs to be eu-population:shared/catalog/EU/Population.

I have checked it again but this does not work. Of course I could create a namespace for each folder or URL-encode the path. The latter might be the most viable way though it is very readable.

Comment: @thhappy: Creating a namespace for each folder structure is what I suggest in my answer. I just edited my answer to show a way how to use the prefixed names with slashes.

Comment: Many thanks, this clarifies the case and the hint to be aware of the difference of the  metadata and the actual reference to the dataset was also very helpful. I am going to check if the